# Need help fixing query/indexes

Tags: mysql, index, optimization

Sorry, I'm a beginner, and I inherited a massive database with huge querying issues.

It's for a forum, and there's a piece of shoddy software (image gallery extension) that is a trainwreck that I'm trying to fix whilst I take some time on the side to finish up my own custom-coded cleaner version that should fix all the issues.

I contacted the extension's coder and he basically stopped responding.

So here's the query:

```
SELECT    p.id_picture, 
          p.commenttotal, 
          p.totalratings, 
          p.rating, 
          p.filesize, 
          p.views, 
          p.thumbfilename, 
          p.title, 
          p.id_member, 
          m.real_name, 
          p.date, 
          p.description, 
          p.mature, 
          c.view, 
          (p.rating / p.totalratings ) AS ratingaverage, 
          v.id_picture                 AS unread, 
          mg.online_color 
FROM      smf_gallery_pic AS p 
LEFT JOIN smf_members     AS m 
ON        ( 
                    m.id_member = p.id_member) 
LEFT JOIN smf_membergroups AS mg 
ON        ( 
                    mg.id_group = IF(m.id_group = 0, m.id_post_group, m.id_group)) 
LEFT JOIN smf_gallery_usersettings AS s 
ON        ( 
                    s.id_member = m.id_member) 
LEFT JOIN smf_gallery_catperm AS c 
ON        ( 
                    c.id_group IN (0,8) 
          AND       c.id_cat = p.id_cat) 
LEFT JOIN smf_gallery_log_mark_view AS v 
ON        ( 
                    p.id_picture = v.id_picture 
          AND       v.id_member = <removed> 
          AND       v.user_id_cat = p.user_id_cat) 
WHERE     (( 
                              s.private = 0 
                                        || s.private IS NULL) 
          AND       ( 
                              s.password = '' 
                                        || s.password IS NULL) 
          AND       p.user_id_cat != 0 
          AND       p.approved = 1) 
                    || (p.approved = 1 
AND       p.user_id_cat = 0 
AND       ( 
                    c.view IS NULL 
                              || c.view = 1)) 
GROUP BY  p.id_picture 
ORDER BY  p.id_picture DESC 
LIMIT     60;
```

Here's the explain:

```
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                                               | key        | key_len | ref                         | rows  | filtered | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+---------+-----------------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | NULL       | ALL    | PRIMARY,id_cat,user_id_cat,id_member,rating,views,commenttotal,totalratings | NULL       | NULL    | NULL                        | 41558 |     9.01 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort       |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | m     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                     | PRIMARY    | 3       | hypnoforum_new.p.id_member  |     1 |   100.00 | NULL                                               |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mg    | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                     | PRIMARY    | 2       | func                        |     1 |   100.00 | Using where                                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | s     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                     | PRIMARY    | 3       | hypnoforum_new.m.id_member  |     1 |   100.00 | Using where                                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | NULL       | ALL    | id_cat                                                                      | NULL       | NULL    | NULL                        |     1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | v     | NULL       | ref    | user_id_cat,id_member,id_picture                                            | id_picture | 4       | hypnoforum_new.p.id_picture |   405 |   100.00 | Using where                                        |
```

I'm kind of at the end of my wits. I haven't done much DB work at all besides the theoretical. Thank you in advance.

Oh, and I almost forgot, here are the query times.

```
# Query_time: 121.589674  Lock_time: 0.000551  Rows_sent: 60  Rows_examined: 27233114  Rows_affected: 0
```

They can range up to 10 minutes...

The server hardware is a Xeon 1270V6 with 32GB of RAM running on 450GB NVMe storage, so I don't think it should be this slow.

Okay, so I have a temporary fix. Apparently, smf_gallery_log_mark_view is the culprit that is causing enormous query times. I believe it is using the entire table in the join for some reason. I deleted all the information in that table, but I would like to eventually achieve a long-term solution. Thanks for anyone reading all of this.

EDIT:

Sorry this is for MySQL and I’m currently running Percona 5.7.

[Here's a db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sSaq9HksYV8F3PvjKMYezz/1) with table CREATE statements and the SELECT query.

Comment: Is `smf_gallery_log_mark_view` a `VIEW`?  Or a `TABLE`?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE...`.

Comment: How many rows in `smf_gallery_catperm` ?

Comment: Very few rows are in `smf_gallery_catperm`, it's holding only about 10-20 rows with just categories of gallery images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many things 'wrong' with the query.  I don't know which are important, nor do I know which can safely be 'fixed'.

**`OR` is hard to optimize.**  There are several cases of `OR`, such as

```
s.private = 0 || s.private IS NULL
```

If practical, consistently pick either `NULL` or `0` for the case in question.  After doing that, we can discuss possible `INDEX` usage.

**The contents of `ON` makes a difference.**  For example:

```
LEFT JOIN smf_gallery_log_mark_view AS v 
ON        (     p.id_picture = v.id_picture 
      AND       v.id_member = <removed> 
      AND       v.user_id_cat = p.user_id_cat )
```

The "right" stuff to put into `ON` is the things that define how the tables are related (the 1st and 3rd items in this case).  The "filtering" (`v.id_member = <removed>`) belongs in the `WHERE` clause.  *In the case of `LEFT`, it matters.*

**Don't use `LEFT` blindly.**  It has a particular usage, and should not be used when it is not needed.  Because of my comment above and my not understanding of the query's goal, I cannot advise on which of these to do:

- Change `LEFT JOIN` to `JOIN`
- Move the filtering to `WHERE`
- or perhaps some other reformulation.

**This *may* be a case of "explode-implode".**  The `JOINs` may expand the number of rows involved (note the `405` in `EXPLAIN`), followed by a collapse (`GROUP BY`).

**`GROUP BY` may be misused.**  There is no 'aggregate' (`COUNT` / `SUM` / ...), so `GROUP BY` should *probably* be replaced by `DISTINCT`.  You may even be getting random values for some columns since perhaps not all columns are related to `p.id_picture`.

**`INDEX(id_picture)` may be useful**.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  If `id_picture` is already the `PRIMARY KEY`, this paragraph is irrelevant.  Having some kind of index on `id_picture` *might* let it avoid `Using temporary; Using filesort`.  `27233114` says that it *probably* does not have such an index, or the Optimizer chose to ignore it.

**`smf_gallery_log_mark_view` might be a `VIEW`?**  If it is, then all sorts of complications could muddy my analysis.

**`innodb_buffer_pool_size`** should be about 20G; is it?  Are the tables all InnoDB?

**...**  Answer some of my questions, deal with some of my suggestions, then I will take another look at things.

Comment: Answers to some of your questions can be found in the linked db-fiddle (which shows the `CREATE` statements for all the tables involved): `smf_gallery_log_mark_view` is a table and `id_picture` is a primary key.

Answer (score 0):

You are using too many left joins, which slowed down the query performance. You need proper indexing on columns which is used in `where` and `ON` clause. 
Id's have primary keys which has already clustered indexes.
You may check statement execution plan by using `EXPLAIN` for proper indexing. `EXPLAIN`is used with an explainable statement, MySQL displays information from the optimizer about the statement execution plan. MySQL explains how it would process the statement.